# GCC fastcall function definition

Tags: c, gcc

Okay, so I can **call** function as **fastcall** CC, by declaring it with `__attribute__((fastcall))`.
How do I define the function itself as fastcall?

Like, I have caller code:

```
// caller.c

unsigned long func(unsigned long i) __attribute__((fastcall));

void caller() {
    register unsigned long i = 0;
    while ( i != 0xFFFFFFD0 ) {
        i = func(i);
    }
}
```

And the function:

```
// func.c

unsigned long func(unsigned long i) {
    return i++;
}
```

In this code, `func()` is being compiled as **cdecl**, it extracts **i** from stack, not from **ecx**(this is i386).

If I write `unsigned long func(unsigned long i) __attribute__((fastcall));` in func.c it just won't compile, saying

```
error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
```

If I declare it in func.c the same way I did in caller.c, it will complain the other way:

```
error: previous declaration of ‘func’ was here
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Attributes must be applied in the declaration, not in the definition.

Try:

```
__attribute__((fastcall)) unsigned long func(unsigned long i) ;
__attribute__((fastcall)) unsigned long func(unsigned long i) {
    return i++;
}
```

The standard way to do this is to put the declaration in a header and have both source files include the header

Comment: func.c:2: error: conflicting types for ‘func’
func.c:1: error: previous declaration of ‘func’ was here

Comment: @einclude try putting the attribute before the definition.  updated response

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the semicolon you put after the attribute.  You need

```
unsigned long func(unsigned long i) __attribute__((fastcall)) // no semicolon here
{
    ... function ...
```